# how to use marquee in html in a error free way?

Tags: html, marquee

I used the marquee tag in my html code. when I was correcting my code in "wcshool markup validation service" http://validator.w3.org/check they showed me an error telling that html body can not handle marquee tag. does anyone know why?

```
<body>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" > <h1>Welcome to Musica.com</marquee>
</body>
```

Comment: Because that isn't a valid html tag. Plus it's annoying so you shouldn't want to be using it anyway.

Comment: W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C. They've been asked to change their name before.

Comment: Ooo! I got carried away with the w3 and w3school! -Blender

Comment: thanks John Conde , I didn't know that. :)

Comment: What doctype were you using for validation?

Comment: is there any valid alternatives for marquee tag ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML> -- Explosion Pills

Comment: @Giliweed: Not using the `<marquee>` tag is an excellent alternative. I have yet to see any good use for it.

Comment: I guess your right. @Blender